# Is there a CSS property like align-self that aligns a flex item on the main axis instead of the cross axis?

Tags: css, flexbox

I thought that justify-self would be this property until I read on MDN Web Docs that it's ignored in flexbox layouts. So, I don't know how to align a single flex item on the main axis like I can on the cross axis using the align-self property. That there would be no counterpart to this property makes no sense to me, so I'd rather not have to resort to roundabout measures. And I don't know if something has changed since this question was asked over four years ago or if the only answer given was right.

Comment: Do you have a code example that is not working?

Comment: https://codepen.io/rrincones/pen/qBKMaQK

I want to bring the <div> flex item down to the bottom of the page while leaving the other <main> flex item centered where it's at. Open to any suggestions, though I was specifically wondering why it can't seem to be done with a flexbox property like align-self that works on the main axis.

Comment: The question is how would all the other flex items on the main axis react to having one item apply `justify-self` ?

Comment: seems it's for a global site structure, I would suggest to use CSS Grid instead of flex, that's really done to do exactly that

Comment: I'll consider Grid in a later scenario. But for now I'm focusing on practicing with flexbox because I'm in the early stages of learning.